ASP.NET Core and React debug front in VSCode
Previously, I created front-end projects separately from the back-end. I decided to create an ASP.NET Core + React project and encountered this problem. I want to develop and debug the project in VS Code. But unfortunately, I discovered that breakpoints, when triggered, simply hang the page in the browser and do not pass anything to the VS Code itself. How to configure a project to achieve work with VS Code?
Default configuration of launch.json:
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "localhost (Chrome)",
      "url": "https://localhost:5173",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}


Hi Прохор Гарагуля, since ASP.NET Core SPA templates are available in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.8 or later , and no more documents about how to use it in vscode. So my suggestion is that you can open two vscode windows, run two projects separately, and then merge them together when the development is completed and deployed.

@JasonPan Hi, i think this is a problem of Vite, couse i created from npm new Vite project and asked my friend did it too. Breakpoints not working. On react-scripts projects this is work fine

My introduction to vite was caught in a problematic VScode build.
This is problem with 1.95 October update of VScode, downgrade to 1.94 solve problem
Commit vscode-js-debug
